# Can't read text file from the data folder or documents folder in the phone's internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-file, android-storage

I am trying to read a hi.txt file present in the "Data" folder inside the phone's internal storage.
I tried the following:

```
try{
File dir = Environment.getDataDirectory();
File file = new File(dir, "hi.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     String line;
     line = br.readLine());
}catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

But, I get the exception: "/data/hi.txt" (no such file or directory)

I am sure the hi.txt file is there!

Same thing happens if I try opening it from the documents folder also in internal storage like this:

```
File dir= new File("/Documents/hi.txt");
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I read a text file that is stored anywhere in the internal storage? like in the DCIM folder or the Documents folder or Movies or Pictures or Music ..etc ?
I need to use a public text file that can be accessed by any application on the phone.

Comment: Do you have permissions in your manifest ?

Comment: @Frank I am not using external storage, so there are no permissions as far as I know.

Comment: No that file cannot be in the /data directory. As who would have put it there? That directory is not writable. And the directory /Documents does not exist to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't add a comment, I have to use answer. 
Have you tried with `Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`, as you are right about the permissions in Manifest, you need them just for external storage. And the other part of the code looks well to me.

Comment: I tried this: File file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/hi.txt"); Didn't work.

Comment: I think this might help
https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148
As there are stated all the methods used for getting files
`getFilesDir() /data/data/package/files` 
Maybe this?